# Crashing mathematica 12.3 with a simple ODE

Tags: differential-equations, crash, precision-and-accuracy

I'm trying to solve an ODE using the following code:

```
f = 1 - (2 M)/r;
F = -3 B (Log[f] + (2 M)/r (1 + M/r));
KGoperator = 
  f/r^2 D[r^2 f D[#, r], r] + (w^2 - q^2/4 f F^2) # &;

q = 1/10^15;
B = 10^10;
M = 1;
rinf = 15000 M;
\[Epsilon] = 1/10^8;
r0 = 2 M + \[Epsilon];

y[r_] = r + 2 M Log[r/(2 M) - 1];

bc1 = Exp[I w y[rr]]/rr /. rr -> rinf;
bc2 = D[Exp[I w y[rr]]/rr, rr] /. rr -> rinf;

upsol = Table[NDSolve[{KGoperator[up[r]] == 
        0, up[rinf] == bc1, up'[rinf] == 
        bc2}, up, {r, r0, rinf}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 15,
       InterpolationOrder -> All, MaxSteps -> Infinity][[
     1]], {w, 1/5, 5, 1/5}];
```

If I don't use this WorkingPrecision, PrecisionGoal, and AccuracyGoal the ODE quickly can be solved. But, unfortunately, some problems appear. These were the minimum values of WorkingPrecision, PrecisionGoal, and AccuracyGoal that apparently are good enough to everything work well.

However, a huge problem is that all my RAM needs to be used as w gets bigger. So, searching for a way to don't crash I started to use this:

```
$Pre = Function[Null, 
   MemoryConstrained[#, 2000000000 - MemoryInUse[]], HoldAll]
```

This prevents the program from crashing, but it also doesn't solve (almost) anything. The real question is: exist some way to, with these specifications about WorkingPrecision etc., solve this ODE?

Comment: I can solve this within mma v12.3 in about 10s without crashing anything and removing all of your requirements....how much ram do you have?

Comment: That's great, give me a lot of hope. I have 8GB of RAM, do you think that's the problem?

Comment: With w -> 30 it balloons up to 10gb so that could very well be the issue if you need w to be higher than that...Have you tried just restarting the kernal and starting from scratch? also avoid using Capital letters for variable names, like F, or KGoperator, MMA functions are always capitals, so you may acidently write over things which ofc can cause problems. start with lower cases always.

Comment: Yes, I tried to restart but the same occurs every time. I'll try to change the name of variables and I bring the feedback.

Comment: How high does w need to be? After i guess 15 or so you’ll have run out of ram

Comment: I would like to use something like -100 to 100 (without w = 0). But -30 to 30 would be great. Unfortunately even changing the name of variables the program is crashing. From w = 1/5 the mathematica is using 95% ram

Comment: Do you need the whole solution or just `up[r0]`, the value at the end of the integration?

Comment: The whole solution

Comment: Maybe try `Method -> "Extrapolation"` or `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`.  They tend to take larger step size, thereby reducing the memory needed. Not sure it will save enough, though

Comment: @Sobrero the values you want are not possible on only 8gb of ram….

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks, I'll try it and I'll give the feedback

Comment: And @DrMrstheMonarch thank you too! Do you think there's something I could do? These results are really important to a work

Comment: @Sobrero either find access to a machine that had more ram, or buy yourself some more assuming Micheals suggestion doesn‘t work, but i‘d assume w -100 -> to 100 is easily more than 64gb of ram